# Difference between og:image:url vs og:image

Tags: facebook-opengraph, share-open-graph

Should my web page include both `og:image:url` and `og:image` or just `og:image`?

Also, do I need to include `og:image:width` and `og:image:height`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [ogp.me](https://ogp.me/), `og:image` is identical to `og:image:url`. In my experience `og:image` has been sufficient.

As for `og:image:width` and `og:image:height`, [ahrefs](https://ahrefs.com/blog/open-graph-meta-tags/) claims they ensure your snippet appears correctly and [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images) says they allow its crawler to render the image asynchronously. In general, I would suggest reading the docs for any bots/crawlers/APIs you anticipate exposing links to so you may adhere to their rules.